# When combining ggplots how can produce just one legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, panel

I have four plots comparing the concentrations of various elements against body mass for two different feeding modes in animals. After combining all graphs into a panel, each individual legend has remained which takes up a lot of space. Is there a way to have just one legend on the side or bottom?

I used the following code;

```
p1<-hgbmplot<-qplot(x = log10bm, y = log10hg, data = data, color = fm) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") + scale_colour_discrete(name="Feeding mode", labels=c("Filter", "Raptorial")) + xlab ("log10(Body Mass (kg))") + ylab ("log10(Hg concentration (μg/g))")

p2<-cumpplot + scale_colour_discrete(name="Feeding mode", labels=c("Filter", "Raptorial")) + xlab ("log10(Body Mass (kg))") + ylab ("log10(Cu concentration (μg/g))")

p3<-sefmplot + scale_colour_discrete(name="Feeding mode", labels=c("Filter", "Raptorial")) + xlab ("log10(Body Mass (kg))") + ylab ("log10(Se concentration (μg/g))")

p4<-ratiofmplot + scale_colour_discrete(name="Feeding mode", labels=c("Filter", "Raptorial")) + xlab ("log10(Body Mass (kg))") + ylab ("log10(Se:Hg Ratio)")

(p1 | p2 ) /
 (p3 | p4)
```

This produced the following graph;
[ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7LIb.png)

Comment: Looks like you are using `patchwork`. In that case try with `+ plot_layout(guides="collect")`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the four legends can only be combined if they have the same properties, such as the same share limits, labels, breaks, and so on. Providing a common legend can be accomplished by sharing a standard scale; one method of achieving this in `patchwork` is to use the `&` operator.

Sample code:

```
 library(patchwork)

p1<-hgbmplot<-qplot(data = data1, x =log2(x), y = log2(y),  color = z) +
              geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
              scale_fill_discrete(name="Feeding mode", labels=c("Filter", "Raptorial")) + 
              xlab ("log10(Body Mass (kg))") + 
              ylab ("log10(Hg concentration (μg/g))")


p2<-cumpplot <-qplot(data = data2, x =log2(x), y = log2(y),  color = z) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Feeding mode", labels=c("Filter", "Raptorial")) + 
    xlab ("log10(Body Mass (kg))") + 
    ylab ("log10(Hg concentration (μg/g))")



p3<-sefmplot <-qplot(data = data3, x =log2(x), y = log2(y),  color = z) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Feeding mode", labels=c("Filter", "Raptorial")) + 
    xlab ("log10(Body Mass (kg))") + 
    ylab ("log10(Hg concentration (μg/g))")

p4<-ratiofmplot <-qplot(data = data4, x =log2(x), y = log2(y),  color = z) +
                            geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
                            scale_fill_discrete(name="Feeding mode", labels=c("Filter", "Raptorial")) + 
                            xlab ("log10(Body Mass (kg))") + 
                            ylab ("log10(Hg concentration (μg/g))")
    

  ((p1 | p2 ) / (p3 | p4)) +  plot_layout(guides = "collect") &
      scale_color_continuous(limits = range(c(data1$z, data2$z,data3$z, data4$z)))
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample data:

```
set.seed(07042020)
x <- runif(50)
y <- runif(50)
data1 <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = runif(50, 0, 2))
data2 <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = runif(50, -1, 1))
data3<-data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = runif(50, 0, 0))
data4<-data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = runif(50, -1, -1))
```